# How can I write the following method in Java 8 streams?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

How can I write the following method in Java 8 streams? I couldn't find a way to do it. This is my code:

```
public static List<ObjectB>  getFilteredList(List<ObjectA> list, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime, int quantity) {

List<ObjectA> objectAList = new LinkedList<>();
List<ObjectB> objectBList = new LinkedList<>();
for (ObjectA object : list) {
    if (object.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isAfter(startTime) && object.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isBefore(endTime)) {
        objectAList.add(object);
    }
}
for (ObjectA objectA : objectAList) {
    int total = 0;
    for (ObjectA object : list) {
        if (object.getDateTime().toLocalDate().equals(objectA.getDateTime().toLocalDate())) {
            total += object.getQuantity();
        }
    }
    if (total > quantity) {
        objectBList.add(new ObjectB(objectA.getDateTime(), objectA.getDescription(), objectA.getQuantity(), true));
    } else {
        objectBList.add(new ObjectB(objectA.getDateTime(), objectA.getDescription(), objectA.getQuantity(), false));
    }

}
return objectBList;}
```

I have a list of objects with two fields: date and quantity. I need to return a list with one object for each date, but with one more feild - boolean, which should be true if the total sum of all quantites per day is more than 16, and false if it's not.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you have trouble with? Some of this converts pretty directly.

Comment: Could you explain in English what the code is supposed to do? Along with sample input / output.

Comment: I am new to Java 8 streams and the biggest problem for me is to do this part: 
for (ObjectA objectA : objectAList) {
    int total = 0;
    for (ObjectA object : list) {
        if (object.getDateTime().toLocalDate().equals(objectA.getDateTime().toLocalDate())) {
            total += object.getQuantity();
        }
    }

Thank you

Comment: Read the Stream tutorial first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/. It will teach you how to do that... You are also recalculating the "total" for each objectA, consider making a `Map<LocalDate, Integer>` first.

Comment: I have a list of objects with date field and integer feild:
"05/20/16 13:30"   "4",
"05/20/16 14:30"    "2",
"05/20/16 17:30"   "12",
"05/23/16 13:10"    "5",
"05/23/16 13:20"   "10"

Comment: And result should be the list with 2 objects: "05/20/16" "18" (if 18>16) "true", "05/23/16" "15" (if 15>16) "false"

Comment: @pvg, Tunaki, I've updated the question with description. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this step-by-step.

- `for (ObjectA object : list) {`: a for loop is usually replaced with `stream()`, so start with `list.stream()`.
- `if (...) {`: condition is usually replaced with `filter()`, so continue with `.filter(object -> object.getDateTime()...)`
- `objectAList.add(object);`: adding the results to the container is usually replaced with `collect()`. You are using `LinkedList()`, but any other List would be fine here, so we will simply use `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

So here's first loop:

```
List<ObjectA> objectAList = list.stream()
    .filter(object -> object.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isAfter(startTime) &&
                      object.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isBefore(endTime))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now let's look into the inner loop which calculates the `total`:

```
int total = 0;
for (ObjectA object : list) {
    if (object.getDateTime().toLocalDate().equals(objectA.getDateTime().toLocalDate())) {
        total += object.getQuantity();
    }
}
```

It's also stream-filter-collect sequence, but here you want to collect the sum. So you may use `IntStream` here which already has the `sum()` method:

```
int total = list.stream()
                .filter(object -> object.getDateTime().toLocalDate().equals(
                                         objectA.getDateTime().toLocalDate())
                .mapToInt(ObjectA::getQuantity).sum();
```

To make your code less crowded I would extract this to the separate method:

```
private static int getQuantityByDate(List<ObjectA> list, LocalDate date) {
    return list.stream().filter(object -> object.getDateTime().toLocalDate().equals(date))
               .mapToInt(ObjectA::getQuantity).sum();
}
```

Now the next `if` statement. It just changes the last boolean argument, so I would rewrite it (even without Stream API):

```
objectBList.add(new ObjectB(objectA.getDateTime(), objectA.getDescription(), 
         objectA.getQuantity(), total > quantity));
```

So now we see that the outer loop becomes stream-map-collect chain and could be rewritten this way:

```
List<ObjectB> objectBList = objectAList.stream()
    .map(objectA -> 
         new ObjectB(objectA.getDateTime(), objectA.getDescription(), objectA.getQuantity(), 
             getQuantityByDate(list, objectA.getDateTime().toLocalDate()) > quantity))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you can notice that collecting into `objectAList` is unnecessary as we just use it to create another stream. So we can merge both loops into single pipeline, resulting in the following final code:

```
private static int getQuantityByDate(List<ObjectA> list, LocalDate date) {
    return list.stream().filter(object -> object.getDateTime().toLocalDate().equals(date))
               .mapToInt(ObjectA::getQuantity).sum();
}

public static List<ObjectB> getFilteredList(
                 List<ObjectA> list, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime, int quantity) {
    return list.stream()
        .filter(object -> object.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isAfter(startTime) &&
                          object.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isBefore(endTime))
        .map(objectA -> new ObjectB(
                objectA.getDateTime(), objectA.getDescription(), objectA.getQuantity(), 
                getQuantityByDate(list, objectA.getDateTime().toLocalDate()) > quantity))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was vary helpful